# User & Address Relationship | One to One | Laravel

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

The `user` table is the child table and the `address` table is the Parent table. is it right?

then the `User` table should have the `address_id` field? (because "child table should have parent_id).

My Problem is,

in this site (https://launchschool.com/books/sql/read/table_relationships) says "address table has `user_id` feild.

what way is right?

Answer (score 1):

Think of "Entities".  Is a "User" an Entity?  Certainly.

Is an Address an Entity?  Abstractly, as a representation of a geographic location -- yes.

So what is the relationship between a User and an Address?

It's actually a many to many relationship.  A User can have many addresses.  Conversely, an address can be the home of many users.  Think of a family: mom, dad, son, daughter, all living in the same home.

There are many cases where people design a system to short cut this, and decide that their business rule is that a person/user can have one and only one address.

This begs the question -- if you are going to do this, then why bother to have a seperate address table?  With that said, relationally speaking, you can share an address amongst multiple users in this manner, by putting a foreign key to address in the User's table.

Another alternative short cut design is to have the rule that a user can have multiple addresses (usually typed as ('home', 'work', 'vacation' etc.)) and to store the user_id in the address row, denoting the ownership of the address by that user.

This rule means that a specific address row can only be owned by one user, and not shared amongst a number of users.

Relational Database design is both an art and a science, although the relationships do constrain your system.

Comment: very thank you for your reply. I have two addresses for one user. Shipping address and billing address.  so, if I put all two addresses in the user table, then the user table gets bigger. that's why I thought to create 3 tables. (user, shipping_address, billing_address) with OneToOne relationship. 

do you have any idea to do this? or should I add shipping and billing fields to the user table?

Comment: Yes.  You Make 2 tables, User and Address.  Each address can have a "type".  Either "shipping", "billing" or "both".  Typically you use either a Char[1] or a tinyint for this where you could use 'S' for shipping or 'B' for billing or 'O' for both.  Or 1 for shipping, 2 for billing and 3 for Both.  Store the user_id in the address table.  This establishes ownership of the address rows by a user.

Comment: It should be obvious that if the shipping and billing address are the same, then only make 1 address row, and type it as 'O' or 3, depending on your type field.  If there are separate shipping and billing addresses, then you store each with the appropriate type.  When you query for addresses for a user, you might have 1 row returned or 2.

Answer (score 0):

Thinking logically **A User can have one or more Address**" while it is also likely that **An Address can have one or more User**. It all depends on the application context.

There are 3 possibilities:

- User has one Address & Address belongs to a User (**One-to-One**)
- User has many Address & Address belongs to a User (**One-to-Many**)
- User has many Address & Address has many User (**Many-to-Many**)

User has greater importance generally in any application context, because besides having one or more address a user can do many things.

#### **Blog site -  One-to-One Relation**

- User can log in
- User can write a Post
- User can comment on a Post
- User can like a Post
- User can follow another User and so on

In the context of a Blog application, Address is just a part of User profile and may be used for some analytics - doesn't warrant importance of multiple addresses

It is only natural to say that in case of a Blog Application

- ***A User has one Address***
  and
- ***An Address belongs to one a User***.

Which means **User is the parent entity** while **Address is child entity**.

Database structure to represent these relations would be like

```
//User: table users
 - id
 - first_name
 - last_name
 - email
 - age
 - password

//Address: table addresses
 - id
 - user_id (references id column on users table)
 - block
 - street
 - city
 - state
 - country
```

And Laravel relationship can be defined as

```php
class User extends Model
{
    public function addresses()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Address::class);
    }
}


class Address extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);    }
}
```

#### **CRM Application - One-to-Many Relation**

In the context of CRM application User can

- Log in
- Raise Complaints/Support Tickets
- View Complaint Status
- Receive notifications
- and so on
- have more than one address: Home & Office

So the User and Address are related in the application context as

- **User has many Address**
- **Address belongs to User**

Database structure to represent these relation would be like

```
//User: table users
 - id
 - first_name
 - last_name
 - email
 - age
 - password

//Address: table addresses
 - id
 - user_id (references id column on users table)
 - block
 - street
 - city
 - state
 - country
```

And Laravel relationship can be defined as

```php
class User extends Model
{
    public function addresses()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Address::class);
    }
}


class Address extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);    }
}
```

#### **Student Management Application - Many-to-Many Relation**

Student can

- Log in
- Make online request for course material, leave application etc
- View Exam schedule
- View Exam results
- Write articles for college newsletter and so on

Student can have more than one address

- Present Address
- Permanent Address

Address can have more than one students

- Students living in a shared accommodation or hostel
- Student whose sibling is also studying in same college

So in this application's context the relations are

- **Student can belong to many Address(es)**
- **Address can belong to many Student(s)**

Database structure to represent these relations would be

```
//Student: table students
 - id
 - first_name
 - last_name
 - email
 - age
 - password

//Address: table addresses
 - id
 - block
 - street
 - city
 - state
 - country

//Pivot: table address_user (joining User and Address)
 - user_id (references id column on users table)
 - address_id (references id column on addresses table)
```

And Laravel relations

```php
class User extends Model
{
    public function addresses()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Address::class);
    }
}


class Address extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);    }
}
```